# Java method to display error if entered a negative value

Tags: java, methods, geometry

The **methods** should display an error message if negative values are used for the circle’s
radius, the rectangle’s length or width, or the triangle’s base or height. I'm not sure how to implement this in the code I have currently.

```
import java.math.*;
public class Geometry  {
    public static double circle(double r){ 
            return Math.PI*r*r;}            
    public static double rectangle(double l, double w) { 
        return l*w;
        }
    public static double triangle(double b, double h){ 
        return b*h/2;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.math.*;
public class Geometry  {
    public static double circle(double r){ 
        if (r < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Radius cannot be negative.");
        }
        return Math.PI*r*r;}            
    public static double rectangle(double l, double w) { 
        if (l < 0 || w < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Length and width cannot be negative.");
        }
        return l*w;
        }
    public static double triangle(double b, double h){ 
        if (b < 0 || h < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Base and height cannot be negative.");
        }
        return b*h/2;
        }
}
```